# CASE WHEN with WHERE

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, case-when

I want to assign a value based on the condition in `CASE WHEN` statement for other rows associated with a `user_id`.

In `step3`, the journey differs. So when `step = 'step3_eu'` then I want to create a column called `type` and assign `'Category 2'` for the rows associated with that `user_id`, else `'Category 1'`.

Here is the sample data:

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| user_id |   step   |     created_at      |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| 7bc6de  | step1    | 2021-01-13 08:47:39 |
| 7bc6de  | step2    | 2021-01-14 06:12:30 |
| 7bc6de  | step3    | 2021-01-18 07:29:16 |
| 7bc6de  | step4    | 2021-01-18 11:10:08 |
| 7bc6de  | step5    | 2021-01-19 08:31:30 |
| 0ee6df  | step1    | 2021-02-08 23:31:55 |
| 0ee6df  | step2    | 2021-02-12 19:50:53 |
| 0ee6df  | step3_eu | 2021-02-13 00:04:34 |
| 0ee6df  | step4    | 2021-02-18 16:42:41 |
| 0ee6df  | step5    | 2021-02-22 08:52:30 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

Here is the desired output:

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| user_id |   step   |     created_at      |    type    |
+---------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| 7bc6de  | step1    | 2021-01-13 08:47:39 | Category 1 |
| 7bc6de  | step2    | 2021-01-14 06:12:30 | Category 1 |
| 7bc6de  | step3    | 2021-01-18 07:29:16 | Category 1 |
| 7bc6de  | step4    | 2021-01-18 11:10:08 | Category 1 |
| 7bc6de  | step5    | 2021-01-19 08:31:30 | Category 1 |
| 0ee6df  | step1    | 2021-02-08 23:31:55 | Category 2 |
| 0ee6df  | step2    | 2021-02-12 19:50:53 | Category 2 |
| 0ee6df  | step3_eu | 2021-02-13 00:04:34 | Category 2 |
| 0ee6df  | step4    | 2021-02-18 16:42:41 | Category 2 |
| 0ee6df  | step5    | 2021-02-22 08:52:30 | Category 2 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+------------+
```

Comment: You should edit your question to explain what you are trying to do.  I for one cannot figure it out at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d655d4d3f5ffe83500caff798244e878)

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
       WHEN bool_or(step = 'step3_eu') OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) THEN 'Category 2'
       ELSE 'Category 1'
    END as type
FROM mytable
```

You can use [`bool_or()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). This checks if there is any record with value `step3_eu` within a group (= partition of `user_id`).